# Deleting from Core Data Swift 4

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a Favorites button that when clicked will add the image of the particular character to CoreData.

```
@IBAction func favButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.isSelected != true {
        saveFav()
    }     
}   

func saveFav() {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let newFav = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Favorite", into: context)
    newFav.setValue((figure?.image)!, forKey: "favFig")

    do {
        try context.save()
        print("Saved!")
    } catch {
        //Process Error
    }
}
```

My question is how do I remove that image from CoreData when clicking the button again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In coredata every object should have Id if you want to delete it , like this

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Favorite> = Favorite.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.predicate = Predicate.init(format: "FavoriteID==\(ID)")

do {
    let objects = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    for object in objects {
        context.delete(object)
    }
    try context.save()
} catch _ {
    // error handling
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to add the ID at the time the button is clicked?

Comment: FavoriteID must be added to the original model structure

Comment: The data is from a JSON file which populates the tableview and detail view controller. Clicking the favButton adds the image to CoreData under "favFig" which is the only attribute.

Comment: you need to add another attribute FavoriteID

Comment: Okay. So what would I put for the setValue?

Comment: you can put indexPath.row

Comment: newFav.setValue(indexPath.row, forKey: "favoriteID") does not work. Is there some other code I need to make that work? The button is in my detail view controller is that matters.

Comment: indexPath.row works for buttons inside tableCell , otherwise you should build your ids according to your logic

Comment: @Sh_Khan, Why would an object need to have an ID to be deleted? That is nonsense.

Comment: @Sh_Khan, most of the time you already have it in memory, either from doing a fetch all or if it has been newly created.

Comment: Does the user will run the app without a close ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan, it's not really clear from the code what is (ID) for? I don't think this solution is the best way even it could work. It's redundant and misleading to make a new ID like FavoriteID, as every CoreData manegedObject HAS an ID yet! It would be better to use that one.

Comment: @Sh_Khan Yes there is a unique key for every managedObject named NSManagedObjectID, see the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectid

Comment: @BootMaker the ID you are talking about is the ID what is used to pass around the moc to different threats, but it is not possible to for example find out in what managedObject particular image is